# read file from memory for regression (R)

Tags: r, ram, glm

when trying to use the shglm function of the speedglm package I have a problem. As the file is too large to read into memory, I wanted to use a link function as outlined in the help pages for the package. The link function is

```
make.data<-function(filename, chunksize,...){       
 conn<-NULL
 function(reset=FALSE){
 if(reset){
   if(!is.null(conn)) close(conn)
   conn<<-file(filename,open="r")
 } else{
   rval<-read.table(conn, nrows=chunksize,...)
   if ((nrow(rval)==0)) {
        close(conn)
        conn<<-NULL
        rval<-NULL
   }
   return(rval)
 }
```

}
}

```
load(ti.RData)
```

I then take my data fram (called ti) and write it to table

```
write.table(ti,"data1.txt",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
```

as in the example here http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/speedglm/docs/shglm. Afterwards

```
da<-make.data("data1.txt",chunksize=10000,col.names=colnames(ti))
rm(ti)
b1<-shglm(T2D~factor(SIBCO)+factor(POCOD),datafun=da,family=binomial())
```

But I get an error

```
Error in dev.resids(y, mu, weights) : 
  argument mu must be a numeric vector of length 1 or length 802
```

I am happy to upload my data set but can somebody maybe roughly tell me where to start debugging? I think when reading in data1.txt through the link function ( with the read.table) some factors in the original data frame are by this operation converted to integers. This is the reason I put factor around the variables. Any suggestion wpould be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that there is probably something wrong with your input data. Without the input data it is hard to say but based on my experience to run shglm with a binomial glm with factors this is where I would start.

As a general debugging strategy you can try something like the following:

- add the lines `debug(shglm)` and `options(error=recover)` to your script
- turn on the `trace=T` option for shglm
- start R and load your script as `source("myscript.R")`
- step through the debugger and use `ls()` to see the variables currently present and inspect them with `dim()` `colnames()` etc.

Now in my experience shglm returns rather cryptic error messages that may change depending on the size of your input chunks (as this changes the data and the factors the model knows about). Below I list a couple of things to check in your data and some common errors that I encountered while getting it to work which may help you to get your own model running.

Regarding the data, make sure that:

- The dependent variable is 0/1 or that it is a proportion 0 <= y <= 1 (in case you have successes and failures, you can use the weights parameter to give the total number of tries and calculate the proportion in the formula, i.e., success/(success + failures), common errors are:

`Error in if (any(y < 0 | y > 1)) stop("y values must be 0 <= y <= 1") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Calls: shglm -> eval -> eval`

- Specify all the levels of the factors (don't forget default values) and make sure that they are sorted, i.e., `factor(age, levels("24andbelow, 25to49, "50to74", "75andover"))`, otherwise you will get errors like:

`Error in crossprod(weights, y) : non-conformable arguments Calls: shglm -> crossprod -> crossprod`

`Error in XTX[rownames(Ax), colnames(Ax)] : subscript out of bounds
Calls: shglm`

Now I did not get your specific error but something close enough that I thought I should mention. Here I tried to supply a formula with two columns (for successes and failures as you can in regular glm), i.e., cbind(success, failures)~factor(var1) + factor(var2)

`Error in dev.resids(y, mu, weights) : 
  argument wt must be a numeric vector of length 1 or length 10
Calls: shglm -> dev.resids`

I guess the main take away is to check your input data.

Comment: It seems like you are *trying* to answer, but this is so rambling and you don't ever actually get to an answer ... it reads like a question.